# Sequence of win streaks

Tags: r

I'm trying to calculate a sequence of win streaks for a binary vector. Given a vector

```
set.seed(2)
x <- sample(c(0,1), 10, replace = TRUE)
[1] 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1
```

I want to calculate the cumulative sum of ones with a "reset" every time there's a zero.
So, in this case, the output of the function should be

```
[1] 0 1 2 0 1 2 0 1 0 1
```

What's the easiest way to do this on R?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

We can use `ave` and create a grouping variable with `cumsum` at every occurrence of 0 in the vector and count the consecutive numbers without 0 in each group.

```
ave(x, cumsum(x==0), FUN = seq_along) - 1
#[1] 0 1 2 0 1 2 0 1 0 1
```

Comment: This will be plenty fast for almost any occasion, but if someone is looking for an Rcpp option for this query - see here https://stackoverflow.com/a/51054267/496803

Comment: This doesn't work if the sequence starts with a success (e.g., `x <- c(1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1)`). I think this should work: `c(ave(c(0, x), cumsum(c(0, x) == 0), FUN = seq_along) - 1)[-1]`

Answer (score 2):

We can use `rleid` with `rowid`

```
library(data.table)
rowid(rleid(x)) * x
#[1] 0 1 2 0 1 2 0 1 0 1
```

#### data

```
x <- c(0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend [runner](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/runner/index.html) package and function [`streak_run`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/runner/versions/0.2.1/topics/streak_run) which calculates consecutive occurences. Possible also calculating on sliding windows (eg. last 5 observations), more in [github documentation](https://github.com/gogonzo/runner)

```
library(runner)
streak <- streak_run(x)
streak[x == 0] <- 0
print(streak)
# [1] 0 1 2 0 1 2 0 1 0 1
```

---

Compare speed with other solutions

```
fun_ave <- function (x) ave(x, cumsum(x==0), FUN = seq_along) - 1
fun_dt  <- function (x) rowid(rleid(x)) * x
run <- function(x) {
  out <- streak_run(x)
  out[x == 0] <- 0
  out
}


microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  run,
  fun_ave(x),
  fun_dt(x),
  times = 1000L
)

# Unit: nanoseconds
#        expr    min       lq       mean   median       uq     max neval
#         run     48     58.5    197.676    207.5    250.0   12599  1000
#  fun_ave(x) 122984 137144.0 173577.501 146211.5 193241.5 3243640  1000
#   fun_dt(x)  24954  28959.0  42959.954  36262.5  40843.0 4141624  1000
```